# Output save file name conflict

Tags: game-maker, windows, savegame

I am making a game in [GameMaker: Studio](https://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker), but I've run into a problem. Originally, the game would create three possible save files:

```
save1
save2
save3
```

The issue is that I have replaced the `"save"` value with `"Save 0"` so the files are generated as:

```
Save 01
Save 02
Save 03
```

The game can generate my save files, but not read them. I determined it is the namespace, as removing it resolves the error. Why does this happen after adding a namespace?

Comment: Do you get a particular error message when trying to load these save files? Is it possibly related to escaping the space character?

Comment: No, they just don't appear on the load screen. They're also wrapped in quotes, so they're declaired properly too. As far as I can tell, the saves are also written properly as well after performing a side-by-side analysis.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli Can you attach the save and load code? It's quite hard to determine anything without anything.

Comment: I figured it out, there was another script containing the original `"sav"` value. I simply tracked it down with the debug mode enabled and replaced the value.